# Does the DB corona-flexibility rule apply to Dutch domestic connections on international journeys?

Tags: trains, germany, covid-19, netherlands

German train tickets bought before 2020-03-14 can be used flexibly until 2020-10-31, including on international trains.  Are they also valid on Dutch domestic connections?

According to [Deutsche Bahn](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/home/info/corona_startseite_bahnde.shtml?dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D001_KIN0001_ar1-startseitenauswertung-Corona-FV_LZ01):

> Nutzen Sie Ihre Fernverkehrs-Fahrkarte, die Sie bis zum 13.03.2020 gekauft haben, flexibel bis zum 31.10.2020. Das gilt auch für Züge des Nahverkehrs, die in der Fernverkehrs-Fahrkarte im Vor- und/oder Nachlauf (mit Kürzel „NV“) genannt sind.
> Das gilt überwiegend auch für internationale Fahrkarten und für Gruppenreisen.

This means that a long distance ticket booked by 2020-03-13 can be used flexibly until 2020-10-31, including connecting local services, and that this mostly also applies for international tickets.

And according to [Nederlandse Spoorwegen](https://www.nsinternational.com/nl/reisinformatie/gevolgen-coronavirus):

> Heeft u vóór 14 maart een ticket voor ICE of IC Berlijn geboekt?
> Dan kunt u uw ticket flexibel gebruiken, voor een reis tot en met 31 oktober 2020. U hoeft geen gebruik te maken van de trein die op uw ticket staat: u mag ook kiezen voor een andere trein. Het is dus niet nodig om uw ticket om te boeken.

This means that if you booked a ticket for the ICE before 14 March, it can be used flexibly until 2020-10-31, and that one can take any train.

I have an international ticket that meets the requirements.  The ticket is clearly valid on the local German train and the ICE from Germany to The Netherlands.  Is it also valid on the connecting Intercity and Sprinter inside The Netherlands, or should I check in with my OV-chipkaart here?

Comment: Good question. (I had a ticket to Basel with extra tickets to Naples. Might be fun to see whether I can use at least one of them.)

Comment: Given that NS in general doesn't do tickets bound to a particular train at all, I guess the answer is "yes". But I'm curious if the scanner in the ticket gate thinks so as well, so have an OV-chipkaart handy. Of course, that only applies if you're departing from the Netherlands. If you're coming from Germany, you may not need to use a NS gate to check in at all.

Comment: @TooTea I actually have a card that can open the gates (I got that from a conductor when I had bought an international ticket from a German machine that didn't or couldn't print codes for scanning a ticket)

Comment: @TooTea Finally I didn't have my card and I couldn't open the gate ("ticket expired"); but there was a information point where I could call for help and explain my situation, then they opened the gate for me.

Answer (score 2):

On the page you are linking to, you can find in the section 'Fragen und Antworten ...' (questions and answers) a more detailed description about what they mean with 'mostly'.

International tickets can be used flexibly until 2020-10-31 with the following restrictions:

- For all trains with compulsory seat reservations, you need a new seat reservation for the train(s) you are intending to use.
- Tickets to and from France can (could) only be used flexibly until 2020-06-30 and you would have needed a new seat reservation for all trains.

Since no restrictions are mentioned here for domestic connections, be it in the Netherlands or anywhere else, I would very much assume that you can use your ticket as you want to.